# My eclipse editor shows no error but when I try to run I can't

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, makefile, libxml2

I'm working on a C project(called `final_01`) in Eclipse, my project has this files: `main.c`, `XMLdataCatcher.c`, `crc.c` and a header `crc.h` and I'am using libxml2 library.

I build the project correctly and it doesn't shows me any error, however when I tried to run, if I run with `ctrl + F11` it doesn't shows me anything in the console, but in the debug shows me this:

```
    final_01 Debug [C/C++ Application]  
    libfinal_01 [3308] [cores: 0]   
        Thread [1] 3308 [core: 0] (Suspended : Signal : SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault) 
            0x1 
    gdb 
<terminated>final_01 Debug [C/C++ Application]  
    <terminated, exit value: -1>/home/practicante/Cworkspace/final_01/Debug/libfinal_01 (11/21/13 4:37 PM)
```

I don't like the "exit value: -1" but I don't know why it appears and the SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault looks weird.

Now, if tried to run doing `right click -> run as -> Local c/c++ Aplication` it shows me a message:

```
Launch Failed. Binary not found
```

But there is a binary in my project and is correctly linked in the run configurations.
(look at this picture, the binary appears! :  http://goo.gl/0M90RT , and this is a picture of the binary linked: http://goo.gl/sjSMQu)

This is my makefile:

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

-include ../makefile.init

RM := rm -rf

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
-include sources.mk
-include subdir.mk
-include objects.mk

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
endif

-include ../makefile.defs

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 

# All Target
all: libfinal_01

# Tool invocations
libfinal_01: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Linker'
    gcc -nostartfiles -L/usr/include/libxml2/libxml -shared -o "libfinal_01" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '

# Other Targets
clean:
    -$(RM) $(OBJS)$(C_DEPS)$(LIBRARIES) libfinal_01
    -@echo ' '

.PHONY: all clean dependents
.SECONDARY:

-include ../makefile.targets
```

I'm using the eclipse debugger, an this is the output(There are a lot of similar lines, the only thing is changing is "00000001" for "00000000", "00000002", "00000003" and so on, but the 00000001 is highlighted)

```
00000001:    Failed to execute MI command:
           -data-disassemble -s 1 -e 141 -- 1
           Error message from debugger back end:
           No se puede acceder a la memoria en la dirección 0x1
```

The las line means: "Cannot access to the memory address 0x1"

I never use a Debugger, what does this mean?

I am lost with this problem.

If you need more information please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Ita

Comment: SIGSEGV means an illegal memory access. If you run it in a debugger it will probably stop where the problem is.

Comment: I'm using the eclipse debugger, an this is the output:(There are a lot of similar lines, the only thing is changing is "00000001" for "00000000", "00000002", "00000003" and so on, but the 00000001 is highlighted)
00000001:    Failed to execute MI command:
           -data-disassemble -s 1 -e 141 -- 1
           Error message from debugger back end:
           No se puede acceder a la memoria en la dirección 0x1

The last line means: "Cannot access to the memory address 0x1"

I never use a Debugger, what does this mean?

PD: I Edit thje post with this information